# Remove option on kendo boolean Filter

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-ui-angular2, kendo-ui-grid, angular-kendo

Im quite new to kendo and Im wondering if there is a way to remove and rename parts of the boolean-filter-cell.
[Picture to show what I mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tzj8y.png)

I would like to remove the Is True option and rename the Is False.

Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do that is to use a custom filter component ([see documentation here](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/filtering/reusable-filter/)).

I have modified the Stackblitz from the documentation to show a custom filter for a boolean column:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-m1ugm3

Have a look at the dropdownlist-filter.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure (I use Kendo for jQuery).

Here's how to update the messages: https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/globalization/localization/messages/#toc-using-the-message-service

Here are the messages you want to override: https://github.com/telerik/kendo-angular-messages/blob/fd6b9e36367c4e9302ecabee240ec5470fcd6cdd/messages/grid/grid.en-US.yml#L78

Hope this helps anyway.